# Spring Batch - Non row based data structure file reader

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a file which is not row based data. It's a text file which contains multiple tables. In order to create one Item I need to take data from several lines. Actually in my case one file is a one record for me, which I have to extract data from several lines to populate item object. 
Example:

```
class DataItem {
   private String price;
   private String quantity;

   //Getters and setters
}
```

Input File is like:

```
Price Data
========================
Price :   150$
Quantity: 4000
-------------------------
```

As given above I need to parse several lines from the file in order to make a one database record (one Item Read).

How can I achieve this using Spring batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FlatFileItemReader` has a couple extension points that will be useful for you.  The `RecordSeparatorPolicy` and the `LineMapper`.

**`RecordSeparatorPolicy`**
The `RecordSeparatorPolicy` indicates to the reader once a full record has been read.  It's `RecordSeparatorPolicy#isEndOfRecord(String record)` takes the current String that has been read and returns `true` if it represents a full record and `false` if not.  In your case, you'll want to develop one that returns `true` once one of the tables has been completely read in.

**`LineMapper`**
The `LineMapper` is a strategy interface that allows the String that represents a record to be mapped to an item.  Simple cases can be addressed by the `DefaultLineMapper` which takes a single String, tokenizes it into a set of tokens via the `LineTokenizer` (represented by a `FieldSet`...a object similar to a `ResultSet` only for files), and passes it to a `FieldSetMapper` that takes the `FieldSet` and maps the tokens to the item to be returned.  You can either implement your own `LineMapper` or you may be able to just implement a  `LineTokenizer` and use the rest of the out of the box components.

With both of these two extension points, I'd expect you to be able to map that data with Spring Batch in a pretty straight forward manor.

Comment: Thank you very much Michael. Good direction you suggested. Could manage with it.